# Capture the VOIP calls receive to a sip phone that send Notificantions to an API on a call

Tags: ip, voip, sip, pbx, softphone

This is whats I'm trying to achieve I want a SIP phone or (is there is any other way I'm open too) to take the calls it receives from a VOIP provider take the information related to the call when someone calls e.g: Call ID, The call it self(maybe) and send i to an Custom API I might have for reporting, a CRM or any other uses we can think of.

Answer (score 1):

You can try tSIP softphone. There are few event types like "on call state" to which Lua scripts can be assigned. From Lua script you can use ShellExecute + curl or other similar utility.

If you need SIP Call-ID or other usually obscure line then it can be extracted from initial INVITE text that Lua can access.